# KnockoutJS: Delete multiple items using checkbox and one delete button

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, sammy.js

I'm developing a single page application using knockout.js and sammy.js.

I know how I can remove one item by attaching a button with a `click` event to each item like so:

```
self.deleteItem = function(item) {
    self.array.remove(item);
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can use checkboxes to remove multiple items at the same time.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding new array to your vm for storing selected rows. Bind it to checkboxes using `checked` binding:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray(["One", "Two", "Three"]);
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();

    self.deleteSelected = function () {
        self.items.removeAll(self.selectedItems());
        self.selectedItems.removeAll();
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selectedItems" />
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Remove Selected" data-bind="click: deleteSelected" />
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zvFnW/

Comment: thanks for this! When I try implementing your code and click on a checkbox it checks all checkboxes. What am I doing wrong? It works in my fiddle but not live for some reason. http://jsfiddle.net/ismailp/zvFnW/2/

Comment: It is hard to say. Try to reproduce it in fiddle. Didn't you forget to add value: $data to checkbox?

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your question. Could you please clarify what doesn't work?

Comment: When I click one checkbox all items get checked! I have vale: $data attached!

Comment: your script only works given that the observableArray looks like so: {"One", "Two", "Three"}. Please check my fiddle with an example on a case it doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/ismailp/zvFnW/4/. What am I missing here?

Comment: In that case you cannot just pass selectedItems to removeAll. You have to get full object from items array. Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvFnW/6/